# Can not use Leaflet with NextJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, leaflet, next.js

I wanna use `Leaflet` with NextJS(typescript).

But Leaflet dose not supported SSR. So, I use `react-leaflet-univarsal`.

Then, I custom Marker Component of Leaflet. So, I wanna use `Leaflet.Icon`.
I tried 2 things.

1. `if(process.browser){}`

This is not found `window`.

2. use dynamic import with `next/dynamic`

```js
let iconPerson: any;
  const DynamicComponent = dynamic(
    () =>
      import('leaflet').then(L => {
        iconPerson = (L as any).Icon.extend({
          options: {
            iconUrl: '/images/icon1.jpg',
            iconRetinaUrl: '/images/icon1.jpg',
            iconSize: new (L as any).Point(60, 75),
            className: 'leaflet-div-icon',
          },
        });
      }) as any,
    { ssr: false },
  );

....

<Marker icon={iconPerson}>
```

This is printed. > Cannot read property 'createIcon' of undefined

Is the way use `L.icon` with NextJS?

Comment: how about react 18 ? any other suggestion ? ```
npm ERR!   react@"18.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.x || ^16.x" from react-leaflet-universal@2.2.1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved this problem by SSR Map component.

In particular,

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Map as M, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet-universal';
import L from 'leaflet';
import { Pois } from '../types/pois';

const iconPerson = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl: '/images/icon1.svg',
  iconRetinaUrl: '/images/icon1.svg',
  iconAnchor: [20, 40],
  popupAnchor: [0, -35],
  iconSize: [40, 40],
});

const MAXIMUM_ZOOM = 18;

type Props = {
  position: { lat: number; lng: number };
  pois: Pois[];
};

const Map: React.FC<Props> = ({ position, pois }) => (
  <M center={position} zoom={MAXIMUM_ZOOM} doubleClickZoom={false}>
    <TileLayer
      attribution='copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />
    <Marker position={position} />
    {pois.map((poi: any) => (
      <Marker position={{ lat: poi.geo.x, lng: poi.geo.y }} icon={iconPerson} key={poi.id}>
        <Popup>{poi.description}</Popup>
      </Marker>
    ))}
  </M>
);

export default Map;
```

```js
const Map: any = dynamic(() => import('./Map') as any, { ssr: false });

return <Map ... />
```

Thank you.

Comment: I did exactly the same as you, but I'm having an error "Uncaught TypeError: promise.then is not a function" I think because when I do the dynamic import, I use `require` instead of `import`. How do you configure to use import like in client-side? @wato9902

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically loading is actually just for components, not libraries.

Libraries that require use of client side APIs will break in SSR but there is a way to get around this.

First, import the library like normal and use it in an effect. Effects only fire on the client after the component is mounted.

If that doesn't work, you can import the library *in* the effect.

Note that componentDidMount() is also viable if you aren't using a functional component.

The equivalent for componentDidMount() in this scenario (see [relevant react docs on equivalents](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-lifecycle-methods-correspond-to-hooks)) would be to use an empty array:

```
useEffect(() => {
/* import the library like normal here if necessary */
/* use the library here */
}, []);
```

For more information you can see [FAQ](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/wiki/FAQ).

Comment: Thank you. But , `import L from 'leaflet'` is not possible by the error "ReferenceError: window is not defined".

Comment: @wato9902 try importing the library within `componentDidMount()`. `componentDidMount() { const { L } = require('leaflet'); }`